# How to set width of Primefaces-Carousel to full page width?

Tags: primefaces, liferay

I have created an Carousel in primefaces/liferay. But it has fixed width and height. So how can I set full page/ full div width of this portlet?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom styles to Primefaces-Carousel by following ways:

> `itemStyle` attribute for inline styling of `<p:carousel>` tag:

```
itemStyle="width:100%;"
```

> `itemStyleClass` attribute for style class of `<p:carousel>` tag:

```
itemStyleClass="fullWidthClass"
```

> OR add width to inside container either through styleClass or style
>   attribute as following:

```
<ice:panelGrid style="width:100%"></ice:panelGrid>
<ice:panelGrid styleClass="fullWidthClass"></ice:panelGrid>
```

**CSS:**

```
fullWidthClass {
    width: 100%;
    /* Other properties */
}
```